# Mocked service returning promise: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am doing unit testing using Karma and Jasmine. I have app.js as main source file:

```
app.service("someServ", function(){
  this.sendMsg = function(name){
    return "Hello " + name;
  }
})

app.factory("appFactory", function ($q, someServ) {
  function getData() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve("Success message");
    return defer.promise;
} 

function foo(){
    var text = someServ.sendMsg("Message");
    alert(text);
}
return {
    getData : getData,
    foo : foo
}
})

app.controller("mainController",['$scope','$http','appFactory',function($scope, $http, appFactory){
var mct = this;
mct.printData = function(){
    var myPromise = appFactory.getData();
    myPromise
        .then(function(data){
            alert("Promise returned successfully. Data : " + data);
        }, function(error){
            alert("Something went wrong.... Error: "  + error);
        })
}
mct.showMsg = function(){
    appFactory.foo();
}
}]);
```

My testFile.js is as follows:

```
   beforeEach(module(function($provide){
    $provide.service("someServ", function(){
        this.sendMsg =   jasmine.createSpy('sendMsg').and.callFake(function(param){})
    });

    $provide.factory("appFactory", function(someServ, $q){
        function getData(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve("Success message");
            return defer.promise;
        }
        function foo(){
            var facParam = "some text";
            someServ.sendMsg(facParam);
        }
        return {
            getData : getData,
            foo : foo
        }
    });
}));

var $scope, mainController, appFactoryMock, someServMock;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $http, $q, appFactory, someServ){
    appFactoryMock = appFactory;
    someServMock = someServ;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    mainController = $controller("mainController", {
        $scope : $scope,
        $http : $http,
        appFactory : appFactoryMock
    });

}));

it('that mainController is calling appFactory methods', function(){
    spyOn(appFactoryMock, "getData");
    mainController.printData();
    scope.$root.$digest();
    expect(appFactoryMock.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
})

it('that appFactory method foo calls someServ sendMsg', function(){
    spyOn(appFactoryMock, "foo");
    appFactoryMock.foo();
    expect(someServMock.sendMsg).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Both the above tests are failing. For first one, error is: `Cannot read property of undefined` and for second one: `expected spy sendMsg to have been called`. First error occurs at: app.js file as shown in call stack. I have also debugged my tests using Debug option in karma chrome window. The `printData()` function is calling actual code in app.js but I have already mocked it.

Please anyone explain me why is it happening so and how to solve this issue? Why original code is being called and how can I make both these tests to pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jasmine's spy only checks if the function has been called, without firing the actual implementation. That's why `getData().then` throws an error.

As you can read [on Jasmine's documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E) you need to add `.and.callThrough()` to go through the original function.

Comment: Hey @Mario, thanks for your reply. I have still one doubt. My test looks like this: 
`spyOn(appFactoryMock, "getData").and.callThrough();
  $scope.$root.$digest();
  mainController.printData();
  expect(appFactoryMock.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();`                          

I am confused that I am calling mainController.printData(); which is actually calling getData of appFactory, then why do I need to use and.callThrough() separately.

Comment: You trust your appFactory to be working, since you are testing the controller, so you don't care about the real implementation: if it's been called, it worked, and that's why we have spies. Why do you still need the mocked implementation then? You call the controller's `printData`, it calls `appFactory.getData` and wants a promise in return: if you don't use `and.callThrough`, the row `myPromise.then` will break since `myPromise` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first issue may be related to a syntax error you have in your code - in your first `it` block, what does the `scope` variable refer to?

Comment: Yes! This was a typo error. scope should have been actually $scope. Thanks.